# text/plain and text/html with c++ mail

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I am using System::Net::Mail to send emails.
I was questioned about is it able to send two versions of email:

1) the html version of email for clients that can read html emails

2) text/plain for people who can't read html emails, and also the html version will be attached

is this possible using System::Net::Mail? I know how to enable HTML body version, but, how to send to types of message?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, but i need to send two versions in the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To let the recipient decide which version she wants to read, the mail needs to be composed using the `multipart/alternative` MIME type. System.Net.Mail supports this by means of the [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.AlternateViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx) collection.